# How parsing works

Tags: beautifulsoup, urllib2

I am trying the sample code for the piracy report.
The line of code:

```
for incident in soup('td', width="90%"):
```

seraches the soup for an element `td` with the attribute `width="90%"`,    correct? It invokes the `__init__` method of the `BeautifulStoneSoup` class, which eventually invokes `SGMLParser.__init__(self)`

Am I correct with the class flow above?

The soup looks like this in the report now:

```
<td class="fabrik_row___jos_fabrik_icc-ccs-piracymap2010___narrations" ><p>22.09.2010: 0236 UTC: Posn: 03:49.9N – 006:54.6E: Off Bonny River: Nigeria.<p/>
<p>About 21 armed pirates in three crafts boarded a pipe layer crane vessel undertow. All crew locked themselves in accommodations. Pirates were able to take one crewmember as hostage. Master called Nigerian naval vessel in vicinity. Later pirates released the crew and left the vessel. All crew safe.<p/></td>
```

There is no `width` markup in the text. I changed the line of code that is searching:

```
for incident in soup('td', class="fabrik_row___jos_fabrik_icc-ccs-piracymap2010___narrations"):
```

It appears that `class` is a reserved word, maybe?

How do I get the current example code to run, and has more changed in the application than just the HTML output?

The URL I am using:

```
urllib2.urlopen("http://www.icc-ccs.org/index.php?option=com_fabrik&view=table&tableid=534&calculations=0&Itemid=82")
```

Comment: The html tags were removed from my soup    <td class="fabrik_row___jos_fabrik_icc-ccs-piracymap2010___narrations

Answer (score 0):

`class` is a reserved word and will not work with that method.

This method works but does not return the list:

```
soup.find("tr", { "class" : "fabrik_row___jos_fabrik_icc-ccs-piracymap2010___narrations" })
```

And I confirmed the class flow for the parse.
The example will run, but the HTML must be parsed with different methods because the `width='90%'` is no longer in the HTML.

Still working on the proper methods; will post back when I get it working.

Comment: I believe you can use `class_` - when searching for attributes, BeautifulSoup will check for `class`. Class also works without any keywords - `soup("tr", "fabrik_row_jos_fabrik_icc-ccs-piracymap2010_narrations")`

Answer (score 0):

There must be a better way....

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.icc-ccs.org/index.php?option=com_fabrik&view=table&tableid=534&calculations=0&Itemid=82")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
soup.find("table",{"class" : "fabrikTable"})
list1 = soup.table.findAll('p', limit=50)
i = 0
imax = 0
for item in list1 :
    imax = imax + 1
while i < imax:
    Itime = list1[i]
    i = i + 2
    Incident = list1[i]
    i = i + 1
    Inext = list1[i] 
    print "Time    ", Itime 
    print "Incident", Incident
    print " " 
    i = i + 1
```